# Liquibase checksums : Based off host?

Tags: database, database-design, liquibase

Do the generation of liquibase changeset checksums take the hostname into consideration or something?

I have a problem were i've ran liquibase on a particular database from our deployment server. However, when i re-run the same group of changelogs from my local machine (against the same database) liquibase attempts to re-execute the changesets therefore throwing errors such as 'table already exists' when actually i'd expect it to detect that they're already been run and skip to just the new changesets.

The path to the changelog-master.xml file is different on each machine? Maybe this is the reason?

If anyone can shed some light it would be greatly apprechiated, and offer a way around this.

Thanks.

Comment: "*The path to the changelog-master.xml file is different on each machine*" - yes that could be a problem. That's one of the reasons I use the `logicalFilePath` attribute in the `databaseChangeLog` tag

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the checksum does take into account the file path, so if that is different on different machines, it will cause problems.